# RSS specification HTML code inside RSS feed

Tags: html, rss

Is HTML code inside the `<description>` tag compliant in RSS 2.0?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The [RSS 2.0 specification](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/encodingDescriptions.html) says that you can include HTML in the description element so long as you properly encode the markup.

You have two ways to do this:

1. Convert tags to escaped HTML entities:

   ```
   <description>this is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;</description>
   ```
2. Wrap the description content within a `CDATA` section:

   ```
   <description><![CDATA[this is <b>bold</b>]]></description>
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You can decode `<` and `>` char to html code

`<` : `&lt;`

`>` : `&gt;`

Comment: You also need to change the ampersand (&) character.

Comment: And to be safe, the `"` and `'` characters too, in addition to `&`, `<` and `>`.

Comment: This is the complete list (5 predefined entities): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML